# How do I know which fairy food I've collected?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-legends

According to some discussions online, as well as my own observations, fairy food needs to be "unlocked" in certain Adventure Mode missions where fairy food is listed as a collectable treasure. After being found and collected at least once, that type of food has a chance to drop from any defeated opponent.

However, unlike everything else that you can collect in Adventure Mode, the checkmark on fairy food disappears after a while. I assume this is because unlike most collectables, it can be found in the same spot over and over again. The problem is that this also makes it look like it hasn't been collected at all.

Is there any way to tell if a food item in a certain mission has been collected before, or if it's something new that has yet to be unlocked?